# has_many relations in Ruby on Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been struggling for some time now with a problem in my Rails app. I have three classes, **Merchandise**, **MerchandiseCategory** and **MerchandiseMerchandiseCategory**. MerchandiseMerchandiseCategory is used to create many-to-many relation between the other two.

When I run the following commands in the Rails Console, I get the corresponding results:

```
m = MerchandiseMerchandiseCategory.first
# Returns an object that relates the first Merchandise
# with the first Merchandise Category

m.merchandise_category
# Returns the corresponding merchandise_category

m.merchandise_category.merchandise_merchandise_categories.first
# Returns an array of all corresponding MerchandiseMerchandiseCategy ids

m.merchandise
# Returns the corresponding merchandise

m.merchandise.merchandise_merchandise_categories.first
# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant
# Merchandise::MerchandiseMerchandiseCategory, expected
# /home/bjarki/Development/h2/app/models/merchandise/merchandise_merchandise_category.rb
# to define it
```

So, all the relations work except the one-to-many relation between Merchandise and MerchandiseMerchandiseCategory. I have tried everything I could think of, including deleting the Merchandise model and recreating it.

These are the classes I'm working with

**merchandise.rb**

```
# branch_id: uuid
# name: string
# price: integer
class Merchandise < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :merchandise_merchandise_categories
  has_many :categories, class_name: :MerchandiseCategory,
                        through: :merchandise_merchandise_categories
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

**merchandise_category.rb**

```
# branch_id: uuid
# name : string
class MerchandiseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :merchandise_merchandise_categories
  has_many :merchandises, through: :merchandise_merchandise_categories
  belongs_to :branch
end
```

**merchandise_merchandise_category.rb**

```
# merchandise_id: uuid
# merchandise_category_id: uuid
class MerchandiseMerchandiseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :merchandise
  belongs_to :merchandise_category
end
```

This has been driving me crazy for the last days. I would be really grateful if anyone could point me towards the right direction.

Comment: I know is not the problematic relationship, but what if you changed in `Merchandise` the relationship to this: `has_many :categories, through: :merchandise_merchandise_categories, source: :merchandise_category`. Another shot in the air, have you tried `spring stop`? Sometimes I've had some problems with rails using old changes of my models/controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but neither worked. I found the solution though, will post it below :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was going on, it was the location of my files.

My app contains rather many models so I decided to create few directories for different components of my app.

The directory I placed these three files in had the name **merchandise**, which apparently is not allowed. I **renamed** the directory to **merchandise_component** and everything worked as it should.

If anyone can explain why I'm not allowed to make that directory have that name, please comment below :-)

Answer (score 0):

put

> merchandise_merchandise_category.rb                                         in
>
> app/models/merchandise/merchandise_merchandise_category.rb

let me know

Comment: This was actually pretty close to my solution though, I will post it. Thanks for your advice :-)